# Show/hide header panel of a page in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to show/hide header panel of a page according to scrolling up/down of a listbox just like facebook home page.

Please help me for the same.

Comment: Have you tried ANYTHING? Are you sure you're the one who's 'creating' this? Please revise [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].